# Could not jump out of a while loop even when I hit a return Java

Tags: java, debugging, while-loop, runtime-error, infinite-loop

Here is my code, when my inputs are {2, 3, 4, 5} and = {1}, I could not jump out of the while loop even when I hit the "return r1". 
The program will print "???", but keeps looping till it gets an index out of bound exception.
It is wired.

```
int[] nums1 = {2, 3, 4, 5}, nums2 = {1};

public static double findMedianSortedArrays(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {

    if(nums1.length > nums2.length) {
        findMedianSortedArrays(nums2, nums1);
    }
    int half = (nums1.length + nums2.length) / 2;
    double l1 = 0;
    double l2 = 0;
    double r1 = 0;
    double r2 = 0;
    int cutR = nums1.length;
    int cutL = 0;
    int cut1 = 0;
    while(cut1 <= nums1.length) {
        cut1 = (cutR + cutL) / 2;
        int cut2 = half - cut1;

        l1 = (cut1 == 0) ? Integer.MIN_VALUE : nums1[cut1 - 1];
        r1 = (cut1 == nums1.length) ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : nums1[cut1];
        l2 = (cut2 == 0) ? Integer.MIN_VALUE : nums2[cut2 - 1];
        r2 = (cut2 == nums2.length) ? Integer.MAX_VALUE:nums2[cut2];

        if(l1 > r2)  
            cutR =  cut1 - 1;
        else if(l2 > r1)  
            cutL = cut1 + 1;
        else {
            if((nums1.length + nums2.length) % 2 == 0) { 
                l1 = (l1 > l2) ? l1 : l2;
                r1 = (r1 < r2) ? r1 : r2;
                return (l1 + r1) / 2;
            } else {
                r1 = (r1 < r2) ? r1 : r2;
                System.out.println("???");
                return r1;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;


}
```

Comment: It is returning, but since you are calling the method recursively, a "return" doesn't actually mean you've exited every instance of this method, only the level at which "return" was called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you recursively call a method, you create a new instance of that method on the stack. Try to think of it as levels and possibly even the movie Inception. You are in the main method and you call run(). You are now in level 1 of run(). If you call run() again while in level 1, you then go to level 2. When you return from level 2, you go back down to level 1. If you return from level 1 you go back to wherever the original run() was called.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I maybe didn't understand correctly what you intended to do but I think your problem is due to this:

```
if(nums1.length > nums2.length) {
    findMedianSortedArrays(nums2, nums1);
}
```

I suppose that your method works if `nums1.length` <= `nums2.length`, if not you just call it after having swapped the parameters.

The problem when it happens  is that you don't do anything with the return value (It succeeded so it outputs `???`) and that you go on afterwards with the wrong parameters and eventually throw an `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

What you just have to do to fix it is to return the value with the parameters in the expected order:

```
if(nums1.length > nums2.length) {
    return findMedianSortedArrays(nums2, nums1);
}
```

Comment: @PengfeiSong You are welcome. Please do not forget to accept an answer if you consider it as the solution. It helps other people having the same problem to find a solution.